# Android Audio fingerprinting implementation

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, gracenote

I am working on an Android app that works similar to shazam, soundhound,
etc. I am using [Echoprint for Android](http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2012/01/25/android-echoprint/) w/ source found on [GitHub](https://github.com/gvsumasl/EchoprintForAndroid) for implmentation of some aspects. In my search I have come across software that aids in this
such as Echoprint, Moomash, ACRCloud, Doreso, and Gracenote. I also came
across soemthing called mufin today (if someone could provide me some more
information on this.) I don't have a large understanding on android
programming but I have been able to manage (about one semester's worth of
java). I have about everything ready on my app except the core component
which is the audio fingerprinting part.

As you may know, Echoprint and Moomash no longer provide an api. I haven't
had any luck with doreso which has left me with Gracenote and ACRCloud
which have free trials or free accounts but those come with limitations.
I am not exactly looking to spend a lot of money in order to get this to
work, so my options seem to be diminishing. When I used the echoprint
code tutorial above, I was able to get it to work and when I tested it,
it seemed to be working but since the echoprint api is no longer
available I was not able to get any results only codegens. I do not have
enough of an understanding of gracenote or acrcloud to implement them
into my app. I tried working with the provided sdks and web api's with no
luck.

For gracenote whenever I did a query with the echoprint codegen I got a
logcat error about not having permission to access the page/site. I looked
into it and it seemed that I needed to incorporate some sort  of user
access in xml within the app and it shouldn't be available for users to
see as it would contain my client ID. I do not know how to do this and
the documentation wasn't very helpful for me. Similar situation with
acrcloud but without the xml user access portion.

That being said, my question is how would I go about implementing my own echoprint server or fingerprinting server that communicates with my app. Would I need services such as google cloud platform/amazon web service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all gracenote is the easiest music identification service i came across.

You are developing for the android and gracenote have their sort of implementation [here](https://developer.gracenote.com/mobile-client-barebones-android-intro) with advantage of very well documented article.

One sample project i found which is very useful to me and i found it [here](https://github.com/tingled/android-quickstart).

I personally made an app with gracenote sample which is working very well and as expected in fact i have tested the app with two different language -> English,Hindi and the response was quite accurate.

I have made app in the Eclipse and i'm trying to migrate it to Android Studio.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you @ChintanDesai, I will try that and see what results I get. Also thank you for the link, looks like it will be really helpful. I will update in a month or so. I wish you the best of luck on the migration.

Comment: @CrescentDesign i have successfully upgrade my app to android studio it was some what tough task because of the native libraries but somehow i managed it.
Thanks and if it helps you please accept it as answer

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I was able to get it to work. Also congrats on a successful upgrade.